# Why the return value is different inside & outside the function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am trying to explore `thisArg` & `filter` array method & just experimenting how `thisArg` can be used & return from `filter`. I have an array and inside the `filter` method I am checking if the value exist in `thisArg` , if not then push the value & finally return `thisArg` from the array filter function.

Inside the filter function logging `thisArg` will show `[1],[1,2],...` but if there is a repeated element it will not be pushed.

On consoling the return from `filter` the repeated value still exist.

I am not able to understand why the `thisArg` value differ inside and outside the `filter` method.

`thisArg` is the optional value.In the below function

```
array.filter(function(item) {}, []) // this empty array is thisArg
```

```js
var x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1];

var m = x.filter(function(item) {
  if (this.indexOf(item) === -1) {
    this.push(item)
  }
  // it will console [1],[1,2],[1,2,3]....
  // will never have repeated value
  console.log("Before Final Return ", this);
  return this; // returning this expecting it will not have repeated value

}, [])
// this will have [1,2,3,4,1]
console.log("Final Value ", m)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filter` expects a true or false return value. Arrays are always truthy. It looks like you meant this:

```js
var x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1];
var m = [];

x.forEach(function (item) {
  if (this.indexOf(item) === -1) {
    this.push(item)
  }
}, m);

console.log("Final Value ", m)
```